# How can I get a value from a class and set it to a variable on a form in C#

Tags: c#, class

I am new to C# and have been working on a database app to practice my programming. I have created a log in form that will retrieve the security level from the users table and set the value to a class. Once the value is in the class, I would like to retrieve the value from the class and set it to a variable in my main form. Once I have the variable I can do some logic to enable or disable access to certain features based on the privilege level. My question is how do I retrieve the value from the class and set it to my variable on my main form?

Here is my log in method on the log in form

```
 private void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = Connection.getConnection();
            conn.Open();

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from \"Users\" where \"UserName\" = :username and \"Password\" = :password;", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("username", Username));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("password", Password));
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            //int i = Convert.ToInt32(result);

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                PrivilegeCheck pc = new PrivilegeCheck();
                Level = dr.GetInt32(3);
                pc.PrivilegeLevel = Level;
                this.Hide();
                frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
                frmMain.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and/or password is incorrect.", "Wrong Login Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                //txtUsername.Text = "";
                //txtPassword.Text = "";
                txtUsername.Focus();
            }

            conn.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and here is my class

```
class PrivilegeCheck
{
    private int privilegeLevel;

    public int PrivilegeLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return privilegeLevel;
        }
        set
        {
            privilegeLevel = value;
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One word of caution ... avoid hard-coding values like you have when reading the field from the database for the security level.  For one thing it is impossible for someone reading the code without having access to the database schema to know what you are actually reading; but also, there is no guarantee that the field position will remain static. Best to get the value using the field-name. If for whatever reason the field-name changes it is much easier to track down than if the database is modified and fields are reordered for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. There are several ways you can do this.

One option is to create a property in your form like so:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private PrivilegeCheck _check { get; set; }

    // Form constructor
    public frmMain(PrivilegeCheck check)
    {
        _check = check;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // ... Use _check in your form.
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
PrivilegeCheck pc = new PrivilegeCheck();
Level = dr.GetInt32(3);
pc.PrivilegeLevel = Level;
this.Hide();
frmMain frmMain = new frmMain(pc); // Pass it to your form
frmMain.Show();
```

Alternatively, you can just make the form's property public like so:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private PrivilegeCheck _privilege;

    public PrivilegeCheck Privilege
    { 
        get { return _privilege; } 
        set
        {
            // Privilege was set, do stuff on your form here.

            // Then store the value
            _privilege = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
PrivilegeCheck pc = new PrivilegeCheck();
Level = dr.GetInt32(3);
pc.PrivilegeLevel = Level;
this.Hide();
frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
frmMain.Privilege = pc; // Set the privilege
frmMain.Show(); // then show the form.
```

Have fun practicing C#! :)

## Update

A third way to do this would be to make your class static, like so:

```
public static class PrivilegeCheck
{
    public static int PrivilegeLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
Level = dr.GetInt32(3);
PrivilegeCheck.PrivilegeLevel = Level; // see here
this.Hide();
frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
frmMain.Show();
```

Then in your form:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    // ... Use PrivilegeCheck.PrivilegeLevel
}
```

Comment: The second option is probably the easier of the two for someone new to c# unless they have experience with other object oriented languages like c++ or java. This answer is also pretty much what @jmcilhinney had recommended in his answer.

Comment: I will give this a try, I apologize but I did leave out a detail. The reason I want to use the class is because the main form is not the only place I want to check the privilege level. It will be checked on multiple forms. I am doing this way to see if it can be done and for a bet of experimentation :)

Comment: @Evanark See my update. You can make the PrivilegeCheck class static and access the PrivilegeLevel property from any form.

Comment: Thank you very much! The third option is exactly what I wanted to accomplish! :) @Scott Prokopetz thank you for the advice about avoiding hard coded value reading from a database. I will use your advice to further advance my knowledge of C# and thank you everyone else, your suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A form is an object like any other.  How would you usually get data into an object?  You'd set a property or call a method and pass an argument, right?  That's what you do here then.  You need to declare the appropriate member in your `frmMain` class and then invoke that member just before displaying the form.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into design patterns, and keeping the example simple, you could simply return the PriveligeCheck type, as opposed to void:

```
public PrivelegeCeck Login(string username, string password) {
{
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from \"Users\" where \"UserName\" = :username and \"Password\" = :password;", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("username", username));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("password", password));
    ...
    ...
    PrivelegeCheck check;
    int privelegeLevel = 0;

    if(reader.Read()) {
       check = new PrivelegeCheck();
       // We try parsing the reader ordinal by passing in the field name reference
       if(int.TryParse(r["<field_name_here>"].ToString(), out privelegeLevel))
          check.PrivelegeLevel = privelegeLevel;
    }

    // Dispose your reader related objects below
    ...
    ...


    return check;
}
```

And somewhere in your form, say on a button click, you could simply call:

```
PrivelegeCheck check = Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
// no user was returned, trow an exception (or how ever you wish to handle that scenario.
if(check == null)
   throw new Exception("User does not exist.");

if(ceck.PrivelegeLevel > 1) {
   ...
   ...
}
```